# using the domain objects in one grails project as a dependency in other grails project

Tags: grails, plugins, multi-project, multi-layer

I have created one grails project that contains all the foundational domain objects. I want to create separate grails projects so it helps me to keep the functional boundaries separate , but,  I have a need to use these foundational domain objects and services as a base dependency so i can use this layer seamlessly in all of my other grails project. Any thoughts on if this is a right approach and some pointers on how to go about doing it is highy appreciated

Comment: You could make it a plugin, but why not just make one REST API that multiple apps talk to to interact with the domain?

Comment: Agree with the first part, not with the second. REST API is not always the best solution; shouldn't be suggested, without adequate knowledge about the requirements and stuff.

Comment: I did think about the REST API as one of the solutions but in the short term I did not want to increase the complexity of my architecture , so thought  having them as a dependency will still help me achieve modularity.

Answer (score 1):

You can make the one, having domain classes, a plug-in, instead. Then, use that plugin in your actual app.

See the [docs](http://docs.grails.org/latest/guide/single.html#plugins), especially the section, **Plugins and Multi-Project Builds**.

Comment: Thank you Adeel Ansari for the suggestion, i will go through the docs and i will let you know if i found what i was looking for